# Is $T(p(x))=p(x+1)$ a linear map if $T:\mathbb{R}[x]\to\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Given $T:\mathbb{R}[x]\to\mathbb{R}[x]$ is $T(p(x))=p(x+1)$ a linear map? $\Bbb{R}[x] $ is a space of all polynomials with coefficients over $\mathbb{R}$.

It seems too easy so I suspect I'm doing something wrong but let:
$$
T(\alpha p(x) + \beta q(x))=(\alpha p + \beta q)(x+1)=\\
=\alpha p(x+1)+\beta q(x+1) = \alpha T(p(x))+\beta T(q(x))
$$
therefore it's a linear map. Is it correct?

Comment: It looks like you have, indeed, the correct idea about what is required. Quibbles: 1) it really should be denoted $T:\Bbb{R}[x]\to\Bbb{R}[x]$, as $\Bbb{R}[x]$ is both the domain and the range here. 2) Similarly, a purist might want to see it written as $T(p)(x)=p(x+1)$ - all because $T$ acts on $p$, and the elements of $\Bbb{R}[x]$ act on $x$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I wasn't sure how to achieve $\Bbb{R}[x]\to\Bbb{R}[x]$ in mathjax. Now I know :)

Comment: Also, for full credit, you should verify that the function $x\mapsto p(x+1)$ is a polynomial function (or just a polynomial, depending on what is meant with $\Bbb{R}[x]$ here. OTOH, this step may have been done in an example in class, and it follows from the observations that A) $(x+1)^n$  is a polynomial (function) for all $n$, and B) substituting $x+1$ in place of $x$ is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: your proof and conclusion are both correct.

Comment: I don't understand why posts like these get flagged. Obviously, this provides an answer to the question as the OP wants confirmation. Do these people actually read the question or do they just think 'Hey a short answer let's flag it!'

Answer (score 1):

---

$$
\text{ Correct. }
$$

$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$

---

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is correct. In fact, the map is even an algebra homomorphism: it also preserves multiplication...